# Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

No meu cenário, tenho as tabelas de usuários e professores, onde um professor tem um usuário, então tenho uma relação `1:1`.

**Migrations:**

*create_users_table*

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 150);
    $table->string('username', 20)->unique();
    $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

*create_teachers_table*

```
Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->date('birth');
    $table->string('about');
    $table->integer('user')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Models:**

*User*

```
protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'remember_token',
];


protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token'
];


public function teacher() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class, 'teacher');
}
```

*Teacher*

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user', 'birth', 'about',
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'user');
}
```

**Controller**
Onde tento criar um professor:

```
$f_teacher = $request->only('birth', 'about');
$f_user = $request->except('birth', 'about', '_token');

$teacher = new Teacher($f_teacher);
$teacher->user()->save( new User($f_user) );
$teacher->save();
```

Ao executar essa página, aparece o seguinte erro:

> **QueryException** in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'user' in 'field list' (SQL:
>
> `insert into users (name, email, username, password, user, updated_at, created_at) values (Nome do professor, professor@email.com, user-prof, senha-criptografada, ,2017-01-07 00:26:44, 2017-01-07 00:26:44)`)

Sei que o erro é porque o *Laravel* está invertendo a relação, está interpretando que a tabela `users` tem o *FK* `user` e a tabela `teachers` não tem, tentei inverter, colocando *HasOne* no modelo do usuário e *BelongsTo* no modelo do professor, mas como esperado não funcionou. Porque essa relação está sendo invertida? Como resolver?

Comment: Esse código do `insert` está certo? Tem duas vírgulas em seguida criando um espaço onde deveria estar o **user**. Eu vi outros exemplos em que as respostas pedem que você preste atenção nas datas. Você tem um [modelo que cria *timestamps*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638487/column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-laravel), mas o banco de dados não tem o campo apropriado para as datas.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway já verifiquei os `timestamps`, esse é justamente o problema, que citei no último paragrafo da pergunta, na verdade a tabela `users` nem tem a coluna `user`, essa coluna é pertencente a tabela `teachers`, mas o Laravel está invertendo o relacionamento que criei. Criei algo parecido com: `Teacher hasOne User` mas ele está interpretando como `User hasOne User`

Comment: Ah, droga, me desculpa! Eu deveria ter lido com atenção. **Back to the lab**

Comment: 1 usuário pode ser um professor é isso? Se for é diferente o migration e os model pra dar certo.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic basicamente sim, pois vou ter dois tipos de usuários, corporações e professores, então unifiquei a tabela de acesso, com os atributos que ambos tem em comum. Então ao meu ver, um professor tem um usuário, assim como corporação terá um usuário.

Comment: Um usuário pode ser os dois professor e corporaçies?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, não, sempre será um para um, usuário funcionaria apenas como um extends para professor e corporação, apenas para reaproveitar campos que os dois tem em comum, para não ter de ter os atributos email, senha etc nas tabelas de professores e corporações.

Comment: @Ivcs eu fiz um apanhado alterei alguns pontos de Teacher (tanto migration quanto model) e criei um registro para você entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>**Relacionamento 1:1 Laravel**</sup>

Seguindo a documentação e os comentários, os `models` e `migrations` precisam ser alterados para se adequar no relacionamento **1:1** proposto pelo [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent).

> `Relação`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> `Migrations`

***Usuario (Users)***

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Users extends Migration
{   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 150);
            $table->string('username', 20)->unique();
            $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

---

***Professores (Teacher)***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Teacher extends Migration
{   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('userid')
                 ->unsigned();
            $table->primary('userid');
            $table->date('birth');
            $table->string('about');
            $table->foreign('userid')
                 ->references('id')
                 ->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('teachers');
    }
}
```

A grande mudança no `migration` é em relação `Teacher`, sendo que a chave da relação não pode ser ***auto-incremento***, porque recebe o valor da chave da relação com `User` e é a ***chave primária*** da tabela `teachers`. Resumindo a **tabela/campo** `users.id` faz relação com `teachers.userid`, gerando assim um relacionamento **1:1**.

> `Models`

`User`

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    //configurações a serem observadas
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $table = "users";
    public $incrementing = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Teacher::class, 'userid','id');
    }
}
```

---

`Teacher`

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Teacher extends Model
{
    //configurações a serem observadas
    protected $primaryKey = "userid";
    protected $table = "teachers";
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = ['userid', 'birth', 'about'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userid', 'id');
    }
}
```

Como já foi dito a mudança também é no model `Teacher`, onde deve ser indicado:

- ***Chave primária***
- ***Desabilitar o auto-incremento desse campo que por padrão é true;***

e está no model nessa parte:

```
//configurações a serem observadas
protected $primaryKey = "userid"; //setando a chave primária
protected $table = "teachers"; //nome da tabela na base de dados
public $incrementing = false; //desabilitando auto-incremento
```

ou seja, quem gera a identificação da relação das tabelas é o model `User` e quem recebe essa chave é o model `Teacher`. `User` tem um `hasOne` com `Teacher`, enquanto `Teacher` tem um `belongsTo` com `User`.

---

**Criar um registro:**

```
//primeiro cria user
$data0['name'] = 'Usuario 1';
$data0['username'] = 'usuario1';
$data0['email'] = 'usuario1@usuario.com';
$data0['password'] = bcrypt('usuario1');
$user = new App\Models\User($data0);
$user->save(); // salva

//depois cria teacher para esse user.
$data1['birth'] = date('Y-m-d');
$data1['about'] = 'Sobre usuario1';
$user->teacher()->create($data1);

//exibindo informações.
var_dump($user->with('teacher')->where('id', $user->id)->first());
```

***Buscando registro:***

```
>>> $c->with('teacher')->find(6);
=> App\Models\User {#731
     id: 6,
     name: "Usuario 1",
     username: "usuario1",
     email: "usuario1@usuario.com",
     created_at: "2017-01-07 12:23:39",
     updated_at: "2017-01-07 12:23:39",
     teacher: App\Models\Teacher {#738
       userid: 6,
       birth: "2017-01-07",
       about: "Sobre usuario1",
       created_at: "2017-01-07 12:23:39",
       updated_at: "2017-01-07 12:23:39",
     },
   }
>>>
```

***Deletando esse registro e relação:***

```
>>> $d = $c->find(6); //busca
=> App\Models\User {#711
     id: 6,
     name: "Usuario 1",
     username: "usuario1",
     email: "usuario1@usuario.com",
     created_at: "2017-01-07 12:23:39",
     updated_at: "2017-01-07 12:23:39",
   }
>>> $d->teacher()->delete(); //excluindo teacher
=> 1
>>> $d->delete(); //excluindo user
=> true
>>>
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)
- [Eloquent: Relationships - One To One](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, ontem um pouco depois de publicar a pergunta tinha alterado as *migrations*, deixando parecido, mas errei no relacionamento das tabelas no modelo. Muito obrigado, entendi o funcionamento do mesmo, não sabia do `incrementing` rs.. Parabéns pela resposta muito bem detalhada :)