# Ajuda com um simples join

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Boa noite, não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, eu tenho duas models, no migration eu criei assim

```
Schema::create('endereco_tipos', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('nome');
         $table->timestamps();
         $table->softDeletes();
     });


Schema::create('endereco', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');            
        $table->string('estado', 2)->default('PR');    
        $table->string('cidade', 300);   
        $table->string('bairro', 300);     
        $table->string('logradouro', 300);
        $table->string('logradouro_numero', 15);
        $table->string('residencia_numero', 15)->nullable();
        $table->string('complemento1', 300)->nullable();
        $table->string('complemento2', 300)->nullable();
        $table->string('responsavel', 300)->nullable();
        $table->integer('endereco_tipo_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('endereco_tipo_id')->references('id')->on('endereco_tipos');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Nas classes eu deixei assim

```
namespace teste;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use Eloquent;

class Endereco extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'endereco';  
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public function enderecoTipo(){
        return $this.hasOne(EnderecoTipo::class, 'endereco_tipo_id');
    }
}

namespace teste;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use Eloquent;

class EnderecoTipo extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'endereco_tipos';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public function endereco(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Endereco::class);
    }
}
```

Dentro do meu controller se eu chamo assim funciona mais não retorna o tipo

```
$todos = Endereco::all();
return view("enderecos.index", ['todos' => $todos]);
```

Não sei como carregar o endereco_tipo junto ao endereco, tentei fazer assim

```
$todos = Endereco::with('enderecoTipo')->get();
```

mas tive um retorno assim -> `Call to undefined function teste\hasOne()`

Tentei fazer assim mas ele carregar o objeto com os dados de endereco misturados com os dados de tipo de endereco

```
$todos = Endereco::join("endereco_tipos", "endereco.endereco_tipo_id", "=", "endereco_tipos.id")->get();
```

Eu gostaria que me retornasse um json assim

```
{ 
    id:15, 
    estado:'asdasda', 
    cidade:'asdada', 
    enderecoTipo : { id: 7, nome: 'Casa', .... } ,
    .....
}
```

Na view eu coloquei assim `{{ $todos }}`, então dei um print_r e é notei que por algum motivo não existe referencia ao `EnderecoTipo::class` dentro do `Endereco::class`

Comment: Sua relação não esta configurada no model por não ser uma chave dentro da convenção ele não faz relacionamentos inclusive tem resposta já no site

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3)

Comment: Olhei o link que passou e não encontrei a solução, pra mim ta dando o erro Call to undefined function teste\hasOne()

Comment: O que seria uma chave dentro da convenção?

Comment: Eu alterei ali no codigo de return $this->belongsTo(Endereco::class); para return $this->hasMany(Endereco::class); mas o erro continua, por favor me ajuda, o link que vc passou não me respondeu nada, o meu relacionamento é 1:N e não 1:1 eu tinha escrito errado, mas continua aparecendo **Call to undefined function teste\hasOne()**

Comment: Se o relacionamento é 1:N eu também já respondi: [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173976/54880), o seu model está puxando errado os namespace e não é herança com Eloquent é com Model, observer tudo isso!

Answer (score 1):

O seus modelos estão todos fora do padrão, estão em `namespaces` diferentes do padrão e quando acontece isso, precisa ser registrado e configurado para que o [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) os reconheçam, sinceramente acho desnecessário, por motivos de perca de padrão, não tem ganho nenhum e fazer assim, etc, ***se não existe razão para fazer assim pra que fazer?***, outro coisa também é que os `use` estão errados, a grafia e configurações também, ou seja, muitos erros, porque, quando diz `function` `teste\hasOne` não definida, já tem o problema onde a herança está feita errada, são muitos erros e vou colocar um ***exemplo minimo*** mediante os dois [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations) disponibilizados de um modelo ideal:

> Enderecotipos (tabela: endereco_tipos)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Enderecotipos extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = array('nome');
    protected $table = 'endereco_tipos';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; 
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];  

    public function enderecos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Endereco::class,'endereco_tipo_id','id');
    }    
}
```

---

> Endereco (tabela: endereco)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Endereco extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = array('estado', 'cidade', 'bairro',
        'logradouro', 'logradouro_numero', 'residencia_numero',
        'complemento1', 'complemento2','responsavel', 'endereco_tipo_id');
    protected $table = 'endereco';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];  

    public function enderecotipo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Enderecotipos::class,'endereco_tipo_id','id');
    }    
}
```

<sup>***Observações:*** observe e compare bem os dois modelos com os seus modelos e verifique tudo que precisa utilizar no seu para dar certo, vale lembrar que eu coloco no `namespace` padrão do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) para os `Model` e vou além, crio um pasta dentro de `app` com o nome de `Models` e organizo minha aplicação assim, mas, fiz de uma maneira padrão para estudos e que servir de orientação para outros também e já existe uma resposta para a sua duvida: [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2) que também pode ser utilizada com referencia.</sup>

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Laravel - Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)
- [Laravel - Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations)

Comment: Só colocando suas classes no lugar das minhas falou que **class  Enderecotipos not found**, mantive o namespace Teste, você falou que eu fiz errado mas eu no inicio rodei **php artisan app:name Teste**,  então quando eu rodei **php artisan make:model Endereco** ele já criou com o namespace Teste, quando eu gerei o controller e as rotas eu gerei pelo artisan. e ele gera com esse namespace Teste. vou criar uma aplicação nova para testar com o namespace padrão do laravel, guenta ai

Comment: Bizarro com o namespace default funciona, uma outra duvida apenas, eu estou fazendo a consulta assim $todos = Endereco::with("enderecotipo")->get(); e funciona, porem quando eu deleto um Enderecotipo ele continua trazendo os enderecos daquele tipo, vem assim { id : 7, enderecotipo : null }, {id : 8, enderecotipo : { id : 15 }} entende? eu gostaria que o item que o endereço tipo está null não mostrasse, tem como?

Comment: @ThiagoSchmitz na verdade você não excluiu o enderecotipo fisicamente no banco, porque ele existe lá já que está usando a softdelete, e isso acontece naturalmente, é assim mesmo, agora você pode filtrar os endereços que possui valor ou não isso é outra duvida, talvez abrir um novo questionamento seria o ideal, e esse já solucionou o problema da sua pergunta, esclareceu melhor?