# Mais de um relacionamento com a mesta tabela

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Possuo uma tabela de Contas a Receber que tem um relacionamento com a Tabela de Clientes e **DOIS** relacionamentos com uma tabela de Plano de Contas*

Eu pesquisei na documentação do Eloquent mas não encontrei como posso fazer estes dois relacionamentos com a mesma tabela. Para a tabela clientes e o primeiro relacionamento com a tabela de Plano de Contas é tranquilo.

Um exemplo bem resumido de como estão minhas tabelas

```
clientes: (id, nome, cpfcnpj)
planocontas: (id, nome, tipo)
recebimentos: (id, data, dtvco, dtpgo, valor, id_cliente, id_planoconta, id_planoconta2);
```

Como fazer o método hasMany dentro da Model PlanoConta para que funcione tanto para o id_planoconta e o id_planoconta2 da tabela de Recebimentos ?

Eu pensei em criar duas novas tabelas, cada uma para uma ligação da tabela de Contas a Receber com a tabela de Plano de Contas, utilizando o relacionamento Many to Many.

Comment: `id_planoconta`, `id_planoconta2` porque tem esses dois campos, qual é a razão ?

Comment: Ola @VirgilioNovic o motivo é que estes dois campos fazem referência a contas separadas do plano de contas. No projeto que estou trabalhando é necessário classificar a conta para indicar do que se trata (id_planoconta) e classificar o seu recebimento (id_planoconta2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O relacionamento nesse caso em especifico fica da mesma [forma informada na  documentação do Eloquent - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships), ***exemplo***:

***Relacionamentos em seu projeto:***

```
class Clientes 
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'clientes';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'cpfcnpj'];

    public function recebimentos()
    {          
        return $this->hasMany(Recebimentos::class, 'id_cliente', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class PlanoContas
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'planocontas';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'tipo'];

    public function recebimentos1()
    {          
        return $this->hasMany(Recebimentos::class, 'id_planoconta', 'id');
    }

    public function recebimentos2()
    {          
        return $this->hasMany(Recebimentos::class, 'id_planoconta2', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Recebimentos
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'recebimentos';
    protected $fillable = ['data', 'dtvco','dtpgo',
                           'valor','id_cliente','id_planoconta', 
                           'id_planoconta2'];   

    public function cliente()
    {       
        return $this->belongsTo(Clientes::class, 'id_cliente', 'id');
    }

    public function planoconta1()
    {       
        return $this->belongsTo(PlanoContas::class, 'id_planoconta', 'id');
    }

    public function planoconta2()
    {       
        return $this->belongsTo(PlanoContas::class, 'id_planoconta2', 'id');
    }
}
```

Ou seja, ***independente da quantidade de relacionamentos***, deve seguir a mesma lógica criando um método `public` para cada uma das chaves e chamando em seu contexto os métodos responsáveis para cada relação.

Alguns respostas já disponibilizadas no site para [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) e [Relacionamentos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships):

- [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Laravel / Eloquent - Consulta em mais de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela/244376#244376)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)
- [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- [One To Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Alguma ideia de como evitar 2 queries para Eager Loading de planoconta1 e planoconta2? Seria muito interessante fazer Eager Loading dos dois relacionamentos em apenas 1 query... :D

Comment: @JhonatanRaul não entendi bem a sua duvida?