# Como fazer o insert 1 para 1, com quatro tabelas em laravel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel

Estou trabalhando com um banco de dados já povoado. Ele possui quatro tabelas (`Aluno`, `clinico`, `Familia` e `TipoCompulsao`), onde `Aluno` recebe *foreignkey* das três tabelas;

**Model aluno**

```
class Aluno extends Model{

public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable =[
                    'Nome','Sobrenome','Cpf','Email','Altura','Telefone','Endereco'
];

public function clinico(){


    return $this->belongsTo(Clinico::class);
}
public function familia()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(Familia::class);
}
 public function tipocompulsao()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tipocompulsao::class, );
```

**model clinico**

```
class Clinico extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable=[
        'hasAnsiedade',
    'hasInsonia',
    'hasHipertensao',
        'hasDiabetes', 
    'hasAlergias', 
    'hasDisturbiosOncologicos',
    'hasProblemasRenais', 
        'hasMenopausa', 
    'hasHipotiroidismo',
    'hasColesterol', 
    'hasFigado', 
    'hasOutros' 
    ];

    public function aluno() {
          return $this->hasOne(Aluno::class );

      }
}
```

**model familia**

```
   class Familia extends Model
{
      public $timestamps = false;
      protected $fillable=[

         'hasObesidade',
    'hasDoencaRenal',
        'hasHipertensao', 
        'hasColesterolGorduraFigado'  

      ];
      public function aluno() {
          return $this->hasone(Aluno::class);

      }
}
```

**Tipocompulsao**

```
    class Tipocompulsao extends Model{

      public $timestamps = false;
      protected $fillable=[
        'hasCompulsaoDoce',
    'hasCompulsaoSalgado'  
      ];

      public function aluno() {
          return $this->hasone(Aluno::class);

      }
}
```

**Controller para salvar dataform **

```
public function test(){

        $dataform=([



            'Nome'=> 'bi',
            'DataNascimento'=>'21-01-1999',
            'Sobrenome'=>'carlos',

        'hasHipertensao'=>'1',

            'hasObesidade'=>'1',
        'hasDoencaRenal'=>'1'



            ]);
    $tipoco=Tipocompulsao::create($dataform);
    $clinico= Clinico::create($dataform);
    $familia=Familia::create($dataform);


    $aluno=$familia->aluno()->create($dataform);
    $aluno=$clinico->aluno()->create($dataform);
    $aluno=$tipoco->aluno()->create($dataform);
```

Estou usando este *script* para salvar; o principal problema é que ele me gera três resultados na tabela `Aluno` um `id` de cada uma das outras tabelas para cada linha, enquanto um só resultado apenas um resultado.

Comment: não manjo de laravel mas achei isso. https://appdividend.com/2017/10/12/laravel-one-to-one-eloquent-relationships/ talvez possa ajudar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3)

Comment: Você poderia ter colocar pelo menos as chaves de relação para ter um exemplo minimo, mas, também já existe pergunta sobre esse tipo de relacionamento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886

Comment: Outro link exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, tem que dar uma revisada. No teu código existe alguns erros de escrita.. Ex. Existe models que tem hasOne tudo minúsculo.

Pra relacionar 1 para 1 usa-se o 'associate':

```
$clinico = Clinico::create($dataform);
$familia = Familia::create($dataform);


$clinico->familia()->associate($familia);
$clinico->save();
```

Para desassociar:

```
$clinico->familia()->dissociate();
$clinico->save();
```

Isto seta a chave estrangeira para null.

Comment: Amigo desculpa  pelos erro de escrita! Estava tentando achar uma solução em tudo quanto e fórum e você salvou minha semana literalmente.Muito obrigada !!!

Comment: Blz mano. Que bom que resolveu.