# Problema com JOIN no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou com um probleminha ao realizar um Join.

Basicamente eu havia feito esse código e estava funcionando, porém tive a necessidade de alterar a chave primaria da tabela 'products' para 'code'.

Após isso, mesmo fazendo as devidas modificações no código, a consulta permanece dando erro, pois chama a chave estrangeira antiga.

Segue o código:

```
function getProducts($name){

    $id = request()->route('order');
    $order = Order::find($id);
    $refPrice = $order->price_id;
    $price = Price::find($refPrice);
    $idCoin = $price->coin_id;

    $items = Product::where('products.description', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
        ->where('products.coin_id', $idCoin)
        ->where('prices.id', $refPrice)
        ->leftJoin('price_items', 'products.code', '=', 'price_items.product_code')
        ->rightJoin('prices', 'price_items.price_id', '=', 'prices.id')
        ->get();

    return view('moduleclient.orders.getproducts', ['items' => $items, 'price_id' => $refPrice]);

}
```

Erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Model Product:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Manufacturer;
use App\Composition;
use App\Type;
use App\Line;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'code'; // or null

    protected $fillable = ['code', 'description','manufacturer_id', 'composition_id', 'register','validity', 'type_id', 'line_id', 'coin_id'];

    public function manufacturer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Manufacturer');
    }

    public function composition()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Composition');
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Type');
    }

    public function line()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Line');
    }
}
```

Comment: Verifique sua model Product. Talvez exista alguma relação com outra tabela que ainda está vinculada ao product_id. O erro que está retornando não parecer ser do inner join, e sim de outra query.

Comment: Adicione o seu Model Product na descrição para que eu possa entender melhor o relacionamento.

Comment: Pronto, adicionei o model acima.

Comment: No fillable você pode adicionar um 'code AS product_id', talvez funcione... Mas aqui ja rodou os comandos do artisan relacionado ao db novamente?

Comment: @Lodi adicionei isso, mas ainda não funcionou, vou tentar um artisan migrate:refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você mudar a chave primária para outro nome não tem problema, mas, o que acontece é que as chaves de relacionamentos você precisa configurar (*existe no Laravel convenção, quando você muda isso, as chaves precisam ser mencionadas nas relações*).

[Exemplo de todas as relações já foi respondido nessa respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152108/54880), então aonde tiver relação com produtos, você precisa mencionar o campo `code`.

***Exemplos:***

- [Relacionamento 1:1 Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175886/54880)
- [Relacionamento 1:N Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173976/54880)
- [Relacionamento N:M Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244376/54880)

todos esses configuram as chave das relações.

*Se você postar todas os `Models` correspondente, coloco uma resposta na integra com as relações que não vai haver problemas, mas, com certeza por uma mudança de nome o código pare de funcionar.*