# Pegar nome da coluna com chave estrangeira

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma tabela produtos que faz referência ao **id** da tabela categorias, mas não quero pegar o número **id** da tabela estrangeira, e sim o nome dessa referência.

Meu controlador está assim:

```
public function index()
{
    $prod = Produto::all();
    return view('produtos', compact('prod'));
}
```

Dai na minha view eu chamo o nome da `categoria_id` mas só recebo o número do ID.

```
@foreach ($prod as $p)
<tr>
    <td>{{$p->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$p->nome}}</td>
    <td>{{$p->estoque}}</td>
    <td>{{$p->preco}}</td>
    <td>{{$p->categoria_id}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Como faço para retornar o nome da categoria que faz referência ao **id** da tabela produtos?

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta colocando a classe `Produto`, principalmente mostrando como implementou a relação entre os modelos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que falta realmente colocar na sua pergunta são as relações de suas duas tabelas, e também os `Models` que são configuradas para essas tabelas, onde um `Produto` tem `Categoria` e uma `Categoria` está em vários `Produto`, ou seja, [um relacionamento 1:N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976). Um exemplo fictio sobre uma tabela de produtos e uma tabela de categorias onde as duas se relacionam, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Classes:***

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'produtos';
    protected $fillable = ['categoria_id','descricao'];

    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Categoria::class,'categoria_id','id');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categoria extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categorias';
    protected $fillable = ['nome'];

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Produto::class,'categoria_id','id');
    }
}
```

---

***Como utilizar:***

```
public function index()
{
    $prod = Produto::with('categoria')->get();
    return view('produtos', compact('prod'));
}
```

---

```
@foreach ($prod as $p)
<tr>
    <td>{{$p->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$p->descricao}}</td>
    <td>{{$p->categoria->nome}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Nesse exemplo tem vários pontos importantes:

- Criar relação das entidades sendo explicito as chaves (se seguir a nomenclaturas de nomes não precisa colocar, mas, é um boa conduta colocar principalmente para manutenção)
- Carregar a relação adianta (comando `with('categoria')`), porque, existe a otimização de somente 2 consultas `SQL` diferente da outra que a cada interação e feita uma nova consulta `SQL` causando lentidão e um erro muito comum no desenvolvimento com `Laravel`.

***Ref.***

- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Laravel / Eloquent - Consulta em mais de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela/244376#244376)