# Laravel - HasOne 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Não tenho problemas com cadastro de dados relacionados em HasOne eu tenho dúvida sobre cadastro de 2 dados hasOne...

Sei que para cadastrar dois dados hasOne é de como segue exemplo:

```
$users = User::create([
            'name' => $request->nome,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'cpf' => $request->cpf,
            'nascimento' => $request->nascimento,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ])->profissionais()->create([
            'formacao' => $request->formacao,
            'rg' => $request->rg,
            'observacao' => $request->observacao
        ]);
```

Como pode ver é o mesmo código sem Area_id, meu problema é o area_id preciso relacionar ele com profissionais também e ele é um dado hasOne.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$users = User::create([
        'name' => $request->nome,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'cpf' => $request->cpf,
        'nascimento' => $request->nascimento,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    ])->profissionais()->create([
        'area_id' => $request->area,
        'formacao' => $request->formacao,
        'rg' => $request->rg,
        'observacao' => $request->observacao
    ]);

    $role = Role::where('name', 'Profissionais')->first();

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    $user->roles()->attach($role->id);
```

A tabela profissionais, tem 2 dados relacionado de User e Area, to usando relacionamento hasOne mas na hora de cadastrar dados relacionado, não consigo cadastrar os dois dados o model profissionais se encontra assim:

```
class Profissionais extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'area_id',
    'formacao',
    'rg',
    'observacao'
];

protected $hidden = [];


public function area() {

    return $this->hasOne(\App\Areas::class, 'id', 'area_id');
}
public function user() {

    return $this->hasOne(\App\User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

}

Migration:

```
Schema::create('areas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('profissionais', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('area_id');
            $table->string('formacao');
            $table->char('rg')->unique();
            $table->string('observacao', 200)->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('area_id')->references('id')->on('areas')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        })
```

Preciso cadastrar profissional relacionado com essas duas tabelas, foi um escopo sugerido pelo meu cliente, qual melhor solução para isso?

OBS: Relacionamento hasOne não aceita Attach...

Comment: O meu é diferente ele lá só faz relacionamento com 1 dado, se você reparar bem tem o area_id que fiz também hasOne então são 2 dados hasOne.

Comment: Só pra pontuar repara direito a dúvida do outro com a minha, a dúvida dele resolvi faz dias minha dúvida é relacionar 2 dados hasOne em 1 tabela...

Comment: Como relatado na outra resposta, poste as suas tabelas deixa eu ver realmente quais são as relações que devem ser feitas ...

Comment: Segue acima a migration de área e profissionais são mesmo arquivo.

Comment: É o que eu disse é belongsTo com hasMany e não tem nada a ver com hasOne. Então o que você quer fazer esta errado.

Answer (score 0):

O relacionamento [mediante migration adicionado na última edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/389332/3) credita a dizer que o relacionamento é 1 para muitos onde `areas` e `users` tem vários `profissionais` e `profissionais` tem uma `area` e um `usuario`

Nesse relacionamento que já tem exemplo aqui no site, fica dessa forma:

```
class Profissionais extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'area_id',
        'user_id',
        'formacao',
        'rg',
        'observacao'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [];

    public function area() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Areas::class,'area_id','id');
    }
    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class,'user_id','id');
    }
}
```

Observação: esse `Model` `Profissionais` tinha as chaves na relação invertidas, mas, agora estão corrigidas

```
class Areas extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    protected $hidden = [];

    public function profissional() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Profissionais::class,'area_id','id');
    }
}
```

Essa seriam as duas relações, como não tenho o contexto geral fica difícil até exemplificar os restantes.

*Talvez você quisesse que a relação de usuários e profissionais fosse* [1:1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886), *mas, como você fez na* `migrations` *é* [1 para N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)

[As operações estão bem explicadas adicionais vide link anexo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175886/54880).

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)
- [1:1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886)
- [1 para N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)