# Pegar o endereço do usuario logado Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tenho um projeto no Laravel 6 e consigo pegar o nome do usuário logado:

```
{{ Auth::user()->nome }}
```

Acontece que o endereço desse usuário está em outra tabela OneToOne onde 1 usuário tem 1 endereço.

Como faço para pegar esse dado de endereço do usuário logado?

```
 {{ Auth::user()->??? }}
```

Seguem os Models:

User:

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->senha;
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'email', 'senha',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'senha','remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function endereco ()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(Endereco::class,'user_id','id');
    }
}
```

Endereço:

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Endereco extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'enderecos';
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'user_id', 'logradouro', 'bairro','numero','cidade','uf','cep',
];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque os dois models na pergunta

Comment: Acabei de adicionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao criar essa função

```
public function endereco ()
{
    return $this -> hasOne(Endereco::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

sua model `User` passa a ter uma referência à model `Endereco`.

Para acessar esse endereço, basta fazer assim `{{Auth::user()->endereco}}` e a partir desse endereço buscar o campo que necessita.

```
{{Auth::user()->endereco->logradouro}}
{{Auth::user()->endereco->bairro}}
{{Auth::user()->endereco->numero}}
{{Auth::user()->endereco->cidade}}
{{Auth::user()->endereco->uf}}
{{Auth::user()->endereco->cep}}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Grata

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma você consegue acessar as informações vinculado ao usuário logado.

```
$user = Auth::user();

$result = Endereco::where('user_id', '=', $user-id)->get();
```

*$result* vai retornar as colunas que você precisa.

Comment: Sim, ok e como eu pego o endereço? São duas tabelas, User e Endereco. O loga no sistema e consigo pegar o nome, mas queria pegar o endereço também?

Comment: Editei, veja se é isso que você precisa.

Comment: Excelente dica! Vou estudar !

Answer (score 0):

Nessa pergunta [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886) já tem um exemplo básico de como acessar a relação e trazer os dados, talvez não seja a melhor forma como você fez `{{ Auth::user()->??? }}` porque se limita a ter que sempre fazer isso para os outros campos, então no seu `controller` ou em uma [View::composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers) ou em uma [View::share](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views), faça:

```
// informações de user logado pelo sistema do laravel
$user = Auth::user(); 
// todas as informações do endereço do usuário logado
$endereco = $user->endereco()->first();
```

e passe para a sua `View` esses variáveis.

Leitura:

- [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3/175886#175886)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108)